# What is Binding event in Jquery plugin exactly for?

Tags: jquery

What is binding event in jquery exactly for? I dont really understand the purpose of it.

```
.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {         
            $("#demo1").css("display", "block");
        })
```

Comment: Post the relevant code that you are referring to?

Comment: What exactlu do u mean by binding an event?

Answer (score 1):

It is binding a custom event and which can be called later using `.trigger`.

```
   //custom event loaded.jstree registered now
   .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {      
        $("#demo1").css("display", "block");
    })
```

You can now call this custom event like,

```
   .trigger('loaded.jstree', ..
```